Differential line driver built with discrete components
I need to establish an SPI communication over one meter in a very noisy environment. To do this, I am planning on using differential communication over a twisted pair cable.
I would use a dedicated IC like the SNx5176B. However, in my application I can only draw power from a 12 V line and the LVDS drivers generally require 5 V. The board has 5 V and 3.3 V sources from an LDO, so they exist, but I'm limited in how much power I can draw from them.
I was planning on using the below circuit:

Ideally, I would add a 100 Ω resistor at the end of the wire as a terminating resistor but that would add a load to the 5 V source.
This works well in LTSpice, but would it work well on a physical board? Is there anything I can do to improve this circuit?

What's the SPI speed? Can't you add a 5V regulator and then some 5V chip like RS-422 or RS-485 transceivers?  Or a dedicated chip for extending SPI? That's far less components than adding several comparators and discrete FETs for all four wires of SPI bus.

If discrete is a requirement, I might first consider current-steering such as used in ECL. Easy to understand and assemble and it uses resistor degeneration to deal with part variations. A differential current is pretty robust over wires. What kind of speed are you hoping to achieve?

So it seems that the main constraint is power draw from the existing 3v3 & 5v supplies.  Why not just make a new 5v supply from the 12V via a buck converter? Then you can use standard SPI chips.

Please establish your requirements first: how noisy is the environment? 10V/m, 30V/m radiated (and comparable conducted)? Or if not by standard, then what noise level do you observe in the real setting, measured on wires, antennas, loops, etc.?  What spectrum is the noise, is there any range you need to be particularly careful with? || What emissions levels must you meet? Crafting a driver is typically a poor idea, as you can't optimize it nearly as well as industry-standard chips have been. Your proposed circuit also lacks input CM range -- a key performance factor in a noisy environment.

I've found in this kind of situation it helps to add a Schmitt trigger buffer on the receiver side; the extra hysteresis helps filter out low-amplitude glitches. I'd also add space for RC filtering where the long cable enters the PCB; initially try with 22 ohm / 100pF if that doesn't hurt your signal bandwidth.

I am targeting 100 kHz for the SPI. Observed noise is around 3V, I don't know the bandwidth because unfortunately I don't have the capability to measure that. @TimWilliams could you clarify your comment regarding the circuit lacking CM range. Do you mean that the receiver can't handle a signal that is brought below GND due to noise? What if I bring the line to 3.3V instead of GND?

Compare the transistor-level design of the SN75176B and LM339A: the former has a 16.8k dividing into 2 x 960R bias resistors, and further circuitry not shown (probably a diff amp); the latter is just a diff amp, which becomes non-functional if the inputs are pushed outside of the supply rails (here, +12/GND). If you consider a noise voltage coupled in series with the pair, you'll see the problem.

There don't actually seem to be many complete(ish) schematics of 485 chips, but there are a few RS-422s, such as: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/national/_dataBooks/1990_400030_National_Interface_Databook.pdf see p. 1-268 (297), DS9639A. DS78LS120 (PDF p.256) may also be of interest.

Thank you @TimWilliams for your detailed and helpful comments. I see the problem of noise pulling the receiver input below GND. I think I will instead drive the line at 5V/3v3 to get a comfortable distance from the power rails. Do you have any thoughts on this updated circuit: https://imgur.com/a/yI4av2n

It's a start. But do avoid asking questions (or for my part, giving answers) in comments. If you have questions on a new schematic, you can ask a new question -- but beware, it will get similar comments as here, and you would most likely be better served by asking about your basic problem in the first place (SPI communication in low-power environment).  If you do, please specify all the constraints that have been asked about here.

Nothing you can whip up with discrete components will work as well or cost as little as off-the-shelf components designed from the ground up to do exactly what you want.
There are dozens of different RS-422 / RS-485 transmitters, receivers, and transceivers.  A better approach is to add a low-power linear regulator such as a 78L05 plus two capacitors, and use these parts to get the excellent noise immunity built into those chips.

You could drive the line directly from the 12V rather than the 5V or 3v3 supplies.  Just design the receiver to handle the higher voltage, older comparator such as LM393 are quite ok for this, or put in a voltage limiter.
For the driver you'll need a complementary pair of switches, so n-chan & p-chan MOSFETs, be careful to drive correctly with deadtime to avoid shoot-thru.   Alternatively you could use commonly available gate drivers for power MOSFETs, this link may help with that:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/710378/341959
